# Android SDK Platform-Tools V.34.0.5 Update stuck at "packing sqlite3.exe"

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-sdk-tools, android-update-sdk

I wanted to update SDK Platform-Tools from V.33.03 to V.34.0.5 . Somehow it gets stuck on "packing sqlite3.exe" for hours.

I already tried starting the whole process again and elinating all tasks running in the background, but it got stuck at the same place again.
Even compleatly uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studios did not change that as soon as I tried updating it again, it got stuck at the same place again.

Is there a work around or anything that I have missed?
I need the update to get the Wifi-Pairing to work again so I can debug my App.
Thanks for your help!